# UIButton layer styling makes application slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I am using UITableView with scrollable cells. Each cell contains nearly 20 to 25 buttons and all the buttons are having border color & radius. Because of this my view controller presentation is very slow. Also application becomes too slow while scrolling the table view.

I have tried duplicating the button once it is created. But the duplicate button doesn't have any border color/radius. This is how I am giving layer style and reusing the button.

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
button.backgroundColor = CRICHQ_GREY;
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
```

For duplicating,

```
NSData *dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:oldButton];
UIButton *clonedButton = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataSave];
```

But when I duplicate the button I am not getting the layer styles in clonedButton button. It gives me plain button so I am supposed to add layer properties again.

I have searched many links but I didn't get any good solution. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395139/i-have-bad-performance-on-using-shadow-effect

Comment: @DogCoffee Not actually. I am not trying to have any shadow just border. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you the .shouldRasterize on the button layer

Comment: No I did not use. Will it make any changes in performance ?

Comment: Give it a shot, it helped one of my apps.

Comment: Tried both Yes/No values but no change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56035/discussion-between-iuser-and-dogcoffee).

Comment: You should show the whole method where you have that code. I made a sample app with 25 buttons in each cell, using the same code you show, and I saw no slowness in loading or scrolling.

Comment: @rdelmar did you check in device ? Because in simulator it works fine only devices are having this problem.

Comment: Yea, I'm seeing that slow performance on an iPhone 4. I've tried various things, but nothing seems to speed it up. I think you might have to rethink your design. Why do you have so many buttons anyway? One thing I didn't try was a rounded background image instead of using layers.

Comment: That's the requirement I got also I wish not overload images when we can do it easily with layers. All I need is to reuse the button. But the problem is when I create duplicate button it doesn't have layer styles. All I get is an normal button.

Comment: +1 for rethinking design. How many buttons would be on screen at any one time? Having so many elements (moving around) on screen at the same time will likely cause significant performance challenges.

Comment: That Part I have handled. I am not loading all the buttons at a time. Only visible buttons will be loaded remaining buttons will be loaded when user scrolls. Still it doesn't give me better performance.

Comment: I don't understand why you think reusing the buttons will help the performance. Every button on screen needs to be rendered, so I can't see how making copies will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your objection is to using a background image instead of layers, but I tried that, and it made the scrolling performance much better on a device. The initial load of the table view controller was still a little slow, but subsequent loads were fast. This is the code I have in my cell class that I used for testing,

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
        button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 44);
        UIImage *bg = [self imageWithView:button];

        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<5; j++) {
                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BT-%d", j*5 + i];
                [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bg];
                button.frame = CGRectMake(60*i + 16, 50*j + 5, 50, 44);
                [self.contentView addSubview:button];
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}


- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height), view.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Comment: You have good point so I have accepted your answer and instead of layer style now I am using image which results in good performance. Thanks for your help.